# I can't displayed values correctly in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

2 weeks ago everything works fine and it displayed all value from Core Data, but yesterday i decided to add new values(because i cleared core data 1-2 weeks ago).
Some people from the chat said to me that probably i save the same value in the core data but i checked it and answer is - No.
I'm trying to explain what's happening here with example:

1. If i add and save value with Title "Aaa" and Location "Aaa" to my InformationOne
   I can display it in my view.
2. If i add and save second value with Title "Bbb" and Location "Bbb" these both "two blue things" taking the last value what i added to my Core Data.
3. If i delete one of them, in the view it will displayed only one of them as it should and it will be "Aaa" or "Bbb" depends on that what i delete(first or second). [Check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWrBa.png)

**Here these values displayed**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var results: FetchedResults<InformationOne>

@State private var deleteBuisness = false
// @State private var testNavigation = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(results) { result in
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(result: result)
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            ListDesignView()
                            VStack(spacing: 3){
                                Text(result.title ?? "Name is not specified")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .fontWeight(.black)
                                    .padding(8)
                                    .background(.black.opacity(0.65))
                                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                                
                                Text(result.kitchen ?? "-")
                                    .font(.footnote)
                                HStack(spacing: 3){
                                    Text(result.address ?? "Location is not specified")
                                        .font(.footnote)
                                    Text(Image(systemName: "location"))
                                        .font(.system(size: 13))
                                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                                    
                                }
                                .offset(x: 80)
                            }
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Text("Results count: \(results.count)")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                Button {
                    // code...
                } label: {
                    Label("Sorting1", systemImage: "chevron.down")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
```

}

**And here i save them**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct AddInfoAbout: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var results: FetchedResults<VisaCard>

@State private var showingReview = false
@State private var isBalanceDeducted = false

@State private var title = ""
@State private var address = ""
@State private var type = ""
@State private var kitchen = ""
@State private var info = ""
@State private var chooseCard = ""

let types = ["Fast Food", "Cafe", "Pizzeria", "Casual Restaurant", "Fine Dining"]
let kitchenTypes = ["Estonian cuisine", "French cuisine", "Italian cuisine", "Mexican cuisine", "Asian food", "National Food"]
let bankCards = ["Visa", "Nothing"]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray
                .opacity(0.4)
            
            VStack(spacing: 30){
                
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                
                VStack(spacing: 15) {
                    // Text("So, let's fill these fields!")
                    // .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    
                    TextField("Name of your restaurant", text: $title)
                        .frame(width: 220, height: 50)
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 3)
                                .opacity(0.8)
                        )
                    
                    TextField("Location", text: $address)
                        .frame(width: 220, height: 50)
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 3)
                                .opacity(0.8)
                        )
                }
                .frame(width: 260, height: 180)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .strokeBorder(.black.opacity(0.7), lineWidth: 4)
                )
                
                VStack(spacing: 5){
                    HStack {
                        Text("Type of the restaurant:")
                        
                        Picker("", selection: $type) {
                            ForEach(types, id: \.self) {
                                Text($0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("Type of the kitchen:")
                        
                        Picker("", selection: $kitchen) {
                            ForEach(kitchenTypes, id: \.self) {
                                Text($0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("Choose the card:")
                        
                        Picker("", selection: $chooseCard) {
                            ForEach(bankCards, id: \.self) {
                                Text($0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .bold()
                .padding([.horizontal, .vertical], 10)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .strokeBorder(.black.opacity(0.7), lineWidth: 4)
                )
                
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("")
                            .bold()
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        showingReview = true
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add more information", systemImage: "info")
                            .bold()
                    }
                    
                    if showingReview {
                        TextEditor(text: $info)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .frame(width: 240, height: 120)
                    } else {
                        //
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        let newInfo = InformationOne(context: moc) // Create a new entity
                        newInfo.title = title
                        newInfo.address = address
                        newInfo.type = type
                        newInfo.info = info
                        newInfo.kitchen = kitchen
                        try? moc.save()
                        dismiss()
                        
                        print("You have money, business is saved!")
                    }) {
                        Text("Save")
                            .frame(minWidth: 50, maxWidth: 100, minHeight: 44, maxHeight: 44, alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .background(Color.accentColor)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddInfoAbout_Previews:         
PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    AddInfoAbout()
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `try?` when saving, use `try` with a do/catch and at least print any error. You have two properties for your environment variable `managedObjectContext` in every view, I don't know if that could cause a problem but it is very confusing. Other than that I find it hard to understand what the actual issue is. Have you checked if everything is persisted properly to your Core Data store or in other words do you know if this is a persistence (Core Data)  issue or a UI (SwiftUI) issue?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i delete one property "managedObjectContext", but still doesn't work. 100% that it saving data in Core Data correctly! Because if i saved something with title "Aaa" and then with "Bbb" and delete first one there will be displayed only one, it depends on that what i delete from CoreData. It looks like ForEach taking data and display it from the last one what i added...

Comment: You are missing a bunch of important code, and have a bunch of unnecessary code to do too much debugging, but one thing that jumped out at me you have `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc` and `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext` in the same view. That leads me to suspect your `PersistenceController` is not set up properly, or not injected properly. Also, @JoakimDanielson is correct. You don't really know what is going on when you throw away your errors.

Comment: @Yrb So, i talked with 5 people from one chat about SwiftUI and two of them told me, that problem can be in the ForEach(results) and yeah, i did like they suggested to me - ForEach(results, id: \.self) ...... and now it works.

Comment: You have some other error causing it. Core Data managed objects already conform to identifiable. If you have to put `id: \.self` to make this work, you have something wrong in your implementation.